# Applocker with local accounts

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I'm trying to configure Applocker on Windows Server 2008 R2. The users for which I'm applying the policy are local user. I've started the AppId Service and set the enforcing mode for the AppLocker to AuditOnly.

In EventLog, I can see message that "allowed" for all applications irrespective of the configured rules. Is there anything else that I can try?\

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ensure that the version of Server 2008 R2 you are using [supports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619725%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) enforcing AppLocker rules.  Web Server and Foundation editions are not supported and will not enforce rules.

I've configured AppLocker with local users before, one thing I had to do was make sure that the default rules were turned off for users with administrative privileges.